# Bits function in Radix-sort

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Radix-sort is the sort keys as the numbers represented in the base of M-number. In order to use Radix sort, I need to understand the bits function.

```
unsigned bits(int x, int k, int j)
{ return (x >> k) & ~(~0 << j); }
```

According to the document I read, it said

> It computes the *j* bits which appear *k* bits from the right of x.

but it's too short and there is some symbol that I hardly understand (i.e `>>`, `~` and `&` ). I made an attempt to test this and it return two value 0 and 1 only.
I really need an explanation about this and the real function of it

Comment: @TomKarzes I know you're a professional but I'm just a newbie. There can be something difficult for me to understand. You can't vote down my question just because I asked something that you know clearly and you force me to know it

Comment: I took the time to answer your question.  You couldn't even be bothered to look up the operators before posting for help.  To me, that's an insufficient amount of effort on your part.  Since you didn't appreciate it, I'll delete my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `unsigned bits(int x, int k, int j)`, `x` is the value to be sorted, `k` is the right most position of the bits to extract from `x`, and `j` is the number of bits to extract from `x`.

If you want to do a radix sort with 4 bit values, you would set `j` to 4 and `k` to the value 0, then 4, then 8, etc.

The function works as follow. First, it shifts `x` by `k` bits on the right. That is done with the expression `(x >> k)`.

The other expression is `(~0 << j)`. The `~0` inverts all the bits of the value 0. This yields a value with all bits to 1. This value is then shifted left by `j` bits. You then get a value with all bits to 1, and the `j` right most bits to 0.

This value get all its bits inverted again due to the ~ operator in front of `(~0 << j)`. You then get a value with all bits set to 0 and the `j` right most bits set to 1.

This value is then combined with an and operation with the result of the first expression `x >> k`. With an and operation, all bits with zero are forced to zero. Since the second expression had all bits to 0 except the `j` less significant. The result is that all bits are forced to 0, except the `j` less significant (right most).

The final result is to return the `j` bits at offset `k` in the value `x`.

If, for instance, the bits of `x` are 100101001 and `k` is 3 and j is 3, the result will be 0000000101.

This is the binary equivalent of extracting a digit from a number.